# Best approach to start client server programming in perl?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, client-server

I need to write a client server application in perl. Many clients will send requests and will be handled via server.

What is best approach to develop such client server application. I searched web and found LWP and IO::Socket as possible contenders.

What is best approach to handle multiple clients? Is this to fork seperate process or use threads to handle many clients.

This is my first time with client-server programming on perl so confused.

Comment: Is it going to be a web server, or something else. A lot of the time in socket programming you can thread the server to accept multiple clients.

Comment: It is not web server in nature. From client machine some requests will go to server and as per content in request server will run some functions on server machine and return output of those functions to client as response.

Comment: Net::Server provides some frameworks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so - the problem with handling multiple concurrent clients is that you need to handle the asychronous incoming data. Normally - reading from a socket (or filehandle) is a blocking operation, which means one client will 'shut out' the others.

There's two major approaches to handling this - one is to read in a nonblocking fashion from your file descriptors, using something like [`IO::Select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html) and `can_read` - then you test which of your sockets has pending IO, process it and repeat.

From the docs:

```
use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket;
$lsn = IO::Socket::INET->new( Listen => 1, LocalPort => 8080 );
$sel = IO::Select->new($lsn);
while ( @ready = $sel->can_read ) {
    foreach $fh (@ready) {
        if ( $fh == $lsn ) {

            # Create a new socket
            $new = $lsn->accept;
            $sel->add($new);
        }
        else {
            # Process socket
            # Maybe we have finished with the socket
            $sel->remove($fh);
            $fh->close;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can multiprocess using `threads` or `forks` - when you do this, you 'split' your process, and run separate instances, each responsible for a single client.

Which of these approaches you take depends very much on what you're trying to accomplish. `fork` is especially good for fast efficient start up, because it's implemented natively on POSIX operating systems. However it's not as friendly for doing interprocess communication (IPC) so if your clients need to communicate... personally, I wouldn't.

As noted in the comments - some basic forking code can be found in [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Internet-TCP-Clients-and-Servers)

Threading is similar to forking - it's not recommended by the perl documentation, because it's *not* lightweight. But it does make the process of communicating between your threads quite a bit easier. I would suggest if you do this, you look at `threads`, `threads::shared` and `Thread::Queue`.

Using a non blocking read approach means you can potentially do all this without having to fork or thread at all, but it only really works if you're doing 'little' things each iteration - each incoming client will stall whilst you process the next, which can mean more latency. (This may not matter though).

Perlmonks has some more examples of different client types: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=436988

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am thinking about using fork approach based on your answer. For each client connection i can simply do forking on server. My client will simply send some argument to server say foo and server will run some script or some command corresponding to foo on server machine and return response generated by script back to client. Is fork bad for this use case?

Comment: No, fork will be fine. The place fork falls apart is if the connected clients need to communicate with each other - then you start having to do all sort of faff to get them to synchronise and communicate.

Comment: Oh then i am good with fork since clients in my case will never ever have to communicate with each other. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Internet-TCP-Clients-and-Servers provides a complete example of a forking tcp socket server (and client)